# After Heroku Deployment Fetching Data Doesn't Return Expexted Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, fetch

I have an react app and I use node.js for the backend. All my request works fine in my local machine. However, after deploying my code on Heroku some, I couldn't get the expected data which is an object. Instead I get html code. Altought one fetch does not works, others work properly. In the fetch that does not give expected data, I get informations about a specific hotel.

To see what I get instead of object, I put logs in useFetch hook.

Here is my useFetch hook to fetch data;

#### useFetch

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const useFetch = (urlEntry) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  
  let url = "";
  

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    url = "api" + urlEntry;
    console.log(url)
  } else {
    url = urlEntry;
    console.log(url)
  }

 

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(url);
        setData(res.data);
        console.log("res.data is")
        console.log(res.data)
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err);
      }

      setLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();

  }, [url]);

  const reFetch = async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    try {
      const res = await axios.get(url);
      setData(res.data);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err);
    }

    setLoading(false);
  };

  return {data, loading, error, reFetch}
};

export default useFetch;
```

When I click on the link that heroku provide for my app and click the place to get specific hotel information, I get html code below.

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta name="viewport" 
content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/><style>*{font-family:"Open Sans",sans-serif;margin:0}</style><title>Best Booking</title><script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.b532b7b6.js"></script><link href="/static/css/main.cb1b4778.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div></body></html>
```

Note: The reason why I reset url to "" is in the useFetch hook, I have proxy in package.json file like "proxy": "http://localhost:8000/api". This prevent deployed app to hit correct endpoint. I have also tried to change this proxy to the domain name heroku app provided me such as "proxy": "https://bbestbooking.herokuapp.com/api". But this didn't work.

Could you please help me with this. This is my firt question. So, I do not know these informations  enough for you. Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you.

Here is the Hotel page that I fetch specific Hotel information

#### Hotel Page

```
import Navbar from "../../components/navbar/Navbar";
import Header from "../../components/header/Header";
import MailList from "../../components/mailList/MailList";
import Footer from "../../components/footer/Footer";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
  faCircleArrowLeft,
  faCircleArrowRight,
  faCircleXmark,
  faLocationDot,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import useFetch from "../../hooks/useFetch";
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { SearchContext } from "../../context/SearchContext";
import { AuthContext } from "../../context/AuthContext";
import { Reserve } from "../../components/reserve/Reserve";

const Hotel = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const id = location.pathname.split("/")[2]; // get hotel id
  const [slideNumber, setSlideNumber] = useState(0);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false); // slider modal open and close state
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false); // slider modal open and close state

  const { data, loading, error } = useFetch(`/hotels/find/${id}`);
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { dates, options } = useContext(SearchContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  //dates between start date and end date
  const MILISECONDS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  function dayDifference(date1, date2) {
    const timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    const diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / MILISECONDS_PER_DAY);
    return diffDays;
  }
  const days = dayDifference(dates[0].endDate, dates[0].startDate);

  const handleOpen = (i) => {
    setSlideNumber(i);
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleMove = (direction) => {
    let newSlideNumber;

    if (direction === "l") {
      newSlideNumber = slideNumber === 0 ? 5 : slideNumber - 1;
    } else {
      newSlideNumber = slideNumber === 5 ? 0 : slideNumber + 1;
    }
    setSlideNumber(newSlideNumber);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (user) {
      setOpenModal(true);
    } else {
      navigate("/login");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Header type="list" />
      {loading ? (
        "Loading"
      ) : (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center mt-5">
          {open && (
            <div className="hidden sticky top-10 left-0 w-screen  bg-black bg-opacity-70 z-50 flex items-center justify-center md:block">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faCircleXmark}
                className="absolute top-10 right-5 text-3xl text-gray-400 cursor-pointer"
                onClick={() => setOpen(false)}
              />
              <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                  icon={faCircleArrowLeft}
                  className="m-5 text-[50px] text-gray-500 cursor-pointer"
                  onClick={() => handleMove("l")}
                />
                <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
                  <img
                    src={data.photos[slideNumber]}
                    alt=""
                    className="h-[600px]"
                  />
                </div>
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                  icon={faCircleArrowRight}
                  className="m-5 text-[50px] text-gray-400 cursor-pointer "
                  onClick={() => handleMove("r")}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
          <div className="mx-8 flex flex-col gap-2.5 relative ">
            <div id="info-and-reserve" className="flex">
              <button
                onClick={handleClick}
                className="absolute right-0 border-none bg-[#0071c2] text-white font-bold cursor-pointer rounded-[5px] text-base px-2.5 py-2 md:py-5 flex"
              >
                <span className="hidden sm:block ">Reserve or</span> &nbsp; <span>Book Now</span> 
              </button>
              <div id="item-info" className="flex flex-col">
                <h1 className="text-2xl">{data.name}</h1>
                <div className="text-xs flex items-center gap-2.5 ">
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLocationDot} />
                  <span>{data.address}</span>
                </div>
                <span className="text-[#0071c2] font-medium ">
                  Excellent location – {data.distance}m from center
                </span>
                <span className="text-[#008009] font-medium ">
                  Book a stay over ${data.cheapestPrice} at this property and
                  get a free airport taxi
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="flex overflow-x-auto scrollbar-hide gap-3">
              {data.photos?.map((photo, i) => (
                <div
                  className="flex-none w-fit flex justify-center"
                  key={i}
                >
                  <img
                    onClick={() => handleOpen(i)}
                    src={photo}
                    alt=""
                    className="h-[250px] object-cover rounded-lg cursor-pointer overflow-hidden md:h-[350px]"
                  />
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-col justify-between gap-5 my-5 md:flex-row ">
              <div className="flex-[3_3_0%]  ">
                <h1 className=" text-2xl">{data.title}</h1>
                <p className=" text-sm mt-5 ">{data.desc}</p>
              </div>
              <div className=" flex-[1.2_1.2_0%] bg-[#ebf3ff] p-5 flex flex-col gap-5  ">
                <h1 className=" text-lg text-[#555] ">
                  Perfect for a {days}-night stay!
                </h1>
                <span className=" text-sm">
                  Located in the real heart of city, this property has an
                  excellent location
                </span>
                <h2 className=" font-light">
                  <b>${days * data.cheapestPrice * options.room}</b> ({days}{" "}
                  nights)
                </h2>
                <button
                  className="border-none px-5 py-2.5 bg-[#0071c2] text-white font-bold cursor-pointer rounded-[5px] "
                  onClick={handleClick}
                >
                  Reserve or Book Now!
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <MailList />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      )}
      {openModal && <Reserve setOpen={setOpenModal} hotelId={id} />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hotel;
```

And here is my hotelController file;

#### hotelController

```
import Hotel from "../models/Hotel.js"; //import hotel model
import Room from "../models/Room.js";

export const createHotel = async (req, res, next) => {
  /* the reason of doing this async is that connection to db,
    trying to create new collection and new document inside will take some time.*/

  const newHotel = new Hotel(req.body); // this is our model, takes body of the request

  try {
    const savedHotel = await newHotel.save(); //try to save the document
    res.status(200).json(savedHotel);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};

export const updateHotel = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    //we find document and we update it with using set method in mongodb.
    //third argument which is option {new: true} set the updatedHotel variable with the new one. without it updatedHotel variable will be the old document but you would see the new one in mongodb
    const updatedHotel = await Hotel.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      { $set: req.body },
      { new: true }
    );
    res.status(200).json(updatedHotel);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};

export const deleteHotel = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await Hotel.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
    res.status(200).json("Hotel has been deleted!");
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};

export const getHotel = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const hotel = await Hotel.findById(req.params.id);
    res.status(200).json(hotel);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};

export const getHotels = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { min, max, ...others } = req.query;
  try {
    const hotels = await Hotel.find({
      ...others,
      cheapestPrice: { $gt: min || 0, $lt: max || 9999 },
    }).limit(req.query.limit);
    res.status(200).json(hotels);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};

export const countByCity = async (req, res, next) => {
  // we need query
  // the endpoint will be like domain/api/hotels/countByCity?cities=berlin,madrid,london
  const cities = req.query.cities.split(","); // cities will be an array
  try {
    const list = await Promise.all(
      cities.map((city) => {
        // return Hotel.find({city:city}).length // this is an expensive solution because it is going to fetch all those data their properties and after that it will find its length
        return Hotel.countDocuments({ city: city }); // instead we use mongoose countDocument method. It just shows its count and it makes it much faster
      })
    );
    res.status(200).json(list);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};

export const countByType = async (req, res, next) => {
  // here we can create a types array like in countByCity (taking types inside our query),
  // But we do not have lots of types although we have lots of cities. We have only 5 items
  // Basically all these types can be fetch one by one

  try {
    const hotelCount = await Hotel.countDocuments({ type: "hotel" });
    const apartmentCount = await Hotel.countDocuments({ type: "apartment" });
    const resortCount = await Hotel.countDocuments({ type: "resort" });
    const villaCount = await Hotel.countDocuments({ type: "villa" });
    const cabinCount = await Hotel.countDocuments({ type: "cabin" });

    res.status(200).json([
      { type: "hotels", count: hotelCount },
      { type: "apartments", count: apartmentCount },
      { type: "resorts", count: resortCount },
      { type: "villas", count: villaCount },
      { type: "cabins", count: cabinCount },
    ]);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};

export const getHotelRooms = async (req, res, nexy) => {
  try {
    const hotel = await Hotel.findById(req.params.id)
    const list = await Promise.all(hotel.rooms.map(room => {
      return Room.findById(room)
    }));
    res.status(200).json(list)
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two different endpoints for development and production? That would make it more difficult to test and debug.

Comment: Any chance `url = "api" + urlEntry;` is supposed to be `url = "api/" + urlEntry;`? Exactly what URL path are you hitting that is returning html instead of hotel information?

Comment: @RockySims I want to hit ` api/hotels/find/:id ` . When I check my console I see that I hit the correct url  but even if I hit the correct url I could not get the info.

Comment: Exactly what url are you hitting? Show me exactly what you paste into the url bar of the browser without any placeholders like `:id`, please.

Comment: I have a proxy like "proxy": "http://localhost:8000/api" which includes "api" however after deploying my app on heroku my app run on https://bbestbooking.herokuapp.com/ for that reason I add "api" word for the production to hit the correct api @Andy

Comment: I am trying to hit https://bbestbooking.herokuapp.com/hotels/62ceb27966ea103de136df24 @RockySims

Comment: I notice the url you've posted doesn't match up with `api/hotels/find/:id` even if you replace the `:id` and add the `bbestbooking.herokuapp.com/` prefix. Did you intend to hit `bbestbooking.herokuapp.com/api/hotels/find/62ceb27966ea103de136df24`?

Comment: Yess you are right, I wat just take it from the browser. Although the browser shows bbestbooking.herokuapp.com/hotels/62ceb27966ea103de136df24  I was hitting bbestbooking.herokuapp.com/api/hotels/find/62ceb27966ea103de136df24 which is correct, @RockySims

Comment: By the way I have edited the question. I have add more code files there. And thank you for helping me @RockySims

Comment: When I hit `https://bbestbooking.herokuapp.com/api/hotels/find/62ceb27966ea103de136df24` I get back what looks like valid hotel data. Are you sure hitting that url returns html for you and not hotel information?

Comment: Looking more closely it appears that when I go to `https://bbestbooking.herokuapp.com/hotels/62ceb27966ea103de136df24` some javascript on that page is hitting the url `https://bbestbooking.herokuapp.com/hotels/api/hotels/find/62ceb27966ea103de136df24` when it should presumably be hitting `https://bbestbooking.herokuapp.com/api/hotels/find/62ceb27966ea103de136df24`.

Comment: The fix may be as simple as changing `url = "api" + urlEntry;` to `url = "/api" + urlEntry;`.

Comment: Thank you very much @RockySims, like you said instead of hitting `https://bbestbooking.herokuapp.com/api/hotels/find/62ceb27966ea103de136df24`, I wad hitting `https://bbestbooking.herokuapp.com/hotels/62ceb27966ea103de136df24/api/hotels/find/62ceb27966ea103de136df24`. When I changed that I could fetch the right data. I am really appreciated. Thank you for your effort.